# Unusual loss progression while training Keras deep learning model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a deep learning model for an image segmentation task. The model I am using is similar to the U-Net architecture and converts a 3-D matrix of normalized(between 0,1) float values to output a binary probability mask of whether each voxel is part the current segmentation. The model is built using keras and looks like this:

```
inputs = Input(shape=patch_shape)

noise = GaussianNoise(2.0)(inputs) 
conv2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu",data_format="channels_first")(noise)
conv2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu",data_format="channels_first")(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2),data_format="channels_first")(conv2)

conv3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu",data_format="channels_first")(pool2)
conv3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu",data_format="channels_first")(conv3)
pool3 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2),data_format="channels_first")(conv3)

conv4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu",data_format="channels_first")(pool3)
conv4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu",data_format="channels_first")(conv4)

up5 = UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2), data_format="channels_first")(conv4)
up5 = concatenate([up5, conv3],axis=1)
conv5 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu",data_format="channels_first")(up5)
conv5 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu",data_format="channels_first")(conv5)

up6 = UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2), data_format="channels_first")(conv5)
up6 = concatenate([up6, conv2],axis=1)
conv6 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu",data_format="channels_first")(up6)
conv6 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu",data_format="channels_first")(conv6)

conv8 = Conv3D(num_y_channel, (3, 3, 3), padding="same", activation='sigmoid',data_format="channels_first")(conv6)
model = Model(input=inputs, output=conv8)
```

I am using a custom loss function specified as:

```
def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
return -(2. * intersection) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f))
```

The input patch size is 40x40x32. I think this task should be relatively straightforward. While training, however, I get the following unexpected behavior:
[Odd loss progression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEF3c.png)

If anyone has dealt with this type of behavior before, advice would be appreciated. I have been checking my inputs, etc. to no success.

Comment: Why are you using custom loss function? most of the cases it is the troublemaker. 

And where are you calling this function, e.g. what is `y_true` and `y_pred` here (what is their shape etc.)?

Comment: I'm using it because it makes more sense for this specific task (image segmentation). The loss function alone isn't an issue. It behaves properly on MNIST with a smaller CNN (even though it isn't really the correct loss to use for MNIST, the loss does consistently decrease over time).

Comment: Input Properties: both the images and labels are numpy arrays (dtype float64) of size (56,1,40,40,32). The labels take on binary values while the images are normalized to be decimal values in the range 0 to 1.